# Can I pass entire UI element into a IValueConverter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, ivalueconverter

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="AddressStackPanel" >
    <ComboBox  Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MatchedAddressList}" DisplayMemberPath="Address" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
    <TextBlock Name="InputtedAddress" Text="{Binding Path=InputtedAddress}"  Foreground={Hopefully pass the UI element to the dataconverter }  />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

The ComboBox has addresses matched by from a geodatabase with the highest scoring value selected. The Textblock has the user-inputted address that was used for matching.  If the address is the same, I want the foreground to be Green, otherwise Red.

I thought maybe I could pass the entire TextBlock into the dataconverter, get its Parent StackPanel, get child 0, cast to a Combobox get the 0th element and compare, and then return red or green.  Is this do-able?

Otherwise I think I have to traverse the visual tree which is just as ugly i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="AddressStackPanel" >
        <ComboBox  Name="ComboBox" 
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MatchedAddressList}" 
                   DisplayMemberPath="Address" SelectedIndex="0" 
                   SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
        <TextBlock Name="InputtedAddress" Text="{Binding Path=InputtedAddress}"  
                   Foreground={"Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, 
                                Converter={x:StaticResource myConverter}}" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Yes.  See [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.self.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` using a converter that compares its value for equality to the `InputtedAddress` and returns `Brushes.Green` or `Brushes.Red` correspondingly.

The tricky part is that the converter mentioned above would need to keep track of `InputtedAdress` somehow; this is quite cumbersome because we can't use `ConverterParameter` to bind, so we 'd need a somewhat involved converter.

On the other hand, the effect can be implemented more easily with an `IMultiValueConverter`. For example:

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MatchedAddressList}" DisplayMemberPath="Address" SelectedIndex="0" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
<TextBlock Name="InputtedAddress" Text="{Binding Path=InputtedAddress}">
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource equalityToBrushConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="ComboBox" Path="SelectedItem" />
            <Binding Path="InputtedAddress" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

You would then need an `IMultiValueConverter` to convert the two incoming values to a `Brush`. This is really easy to make using the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx)-provided example.