# How Do You Bind To An Item In A Dictionary?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dictionary, datatemplate

I'm using the RadCarousel control from Telerik in a WPF application with C#.  RadCarousel  is similar to a GridView in that it binds to a collection and show's each item in the collection (so my question isn't specific to Telerik or RadCarousel).

I'm using a DataTemplate to specify how each record should get displayed.

If I do this it work's fine:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=oMySubObject.TheAmount}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

But what if I need to point to an item in a dictionary?

```
<DataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=myDictionaryOfSubObjects[TheCurrentIndex].TheAmount}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

This I can't get working and don't know how.  Basically...I need the index to be specified at runtime and when it gets updated, the binding updates.

Any advice?

Comment: [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)...

Comment: @Nullqwerty You also might want to try binding directly to the Dictionary.Values, not sure it it will work, but its worth a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
  <NAMESPACEWHERECONVERTERRESIDES:DictionaryConverter x:Key="cDictionaryConverter"/>
</WindowResources>


    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=myDictionaryOfSubObjects, Converter={StaticResource cDictionaryConverter}}"/>
```

// Something like this:

```c#
[ValueConversion(typeof(Dictionary), typeof(string))]
public class DictionaryConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
         Dictionary<type, type> dict = value as Dictionary<type, type>; 
         return dict[CurrentIndex].TheAmount; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this.  So, here's the kicker though...what if I actually have 20 textblocks each pointing to a different property other than "TheAmount".  Would I need a different Coverter for each?

Comment: @Nullqwerty You can pass the entire control through an IValueConverter.  So you could name your control "AmountControl", then pass it through the conveter, then get the datacontext to grab the dict, then you have some logic like "if name is AmountControl" return .TheAmount

Comment: @Nullqwerty http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350388/can-i-pass-entire-ui-element-into-a-ivalueconverter

Answer (score 1):

You can only use constant values in the indexer, `TheCurrentIndex` will not be resolved. There are a few workarounds, like passing the dictionary and the index to a [multi value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to resolve the item there.

Comment: That's the type of solution I'm trying to find.  Coming up short though.

Answer (score 0):

With anything complicated, you should probably make a getter that does the job, and bind to that.

What is "TheCurrentIndex"?

Comment: Thanks.  TheCurrentIndex is just a property specifying the index.  I can do that and I have done it as a workaround.  It just doesn't fit nicely into my Library for other various reasons.  Was hoping for the binding to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="QuizBee.Host.Window1"
        x:Name="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window1, Path=myDictionary}" />
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Window1:Window
{
    // the property must be public, and it must have a getter & setter
    public Dictionary<string, myClass> myDictionary { get; set; }

    public Window1()
    {
        // define the dictionary items in the constructor
        // do the defining BEFORE the InitializeComponent();

        myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, myClass>()
        {
            {"item 1", new myClass(1)},
            {"item 2", new myClass(2)},
            {"item 3", new myClass(3)},
            {"item 4", new myClass(4)},
            {"item 5", new myClass(5)},
        }; 

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```